# How do I tell Google Vision OCR Api that image is numerical numbers only?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-vision

I am using Google Vision OCR Api to convert a ton of handwriting into keyed text. Large segments of the data is numerical only, but sometimes Google Vision returns alpha characters instead. Often the handwriting is really sloppy so I am not shocked that this is happening.

Is there anyway to tell the Api that the image only includes numbers and no letters?

I have read documentation on Google Vision, but have not found anything that would achieve this.

gcloud ml vision detect-document "https://myimage.png"

I am hoping that if Google Vision knows in advance that the image only contains numbers, then perhaps it will make it easier and more likely to recognize the correct numbers.